# Loading Cassandra Data into Dask Dataframe

Tags: dask

I am trying to load data from a cassandra database into a Dask dataframe. I have tried querying the following with no success:

```
query="""SELECT * FROM document_table"""
df = man.session.execute(query)
df = dd.DataFrame(list(df))
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-135-021507f6f2ab> in <module>()
----> 1 a = dd.DataFrame(list(df))

    TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'name', 'meta', and 'divisions'
```

Does anybody know an easy way to load data directly from Cassandra into Dask? It is too much memory too load into pandas first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problems with your code:

- the line `df =` presumably loads the whole data-set into memory. Dask is not invoked here, it plays no part in this. Someone with knowledge of the Cassandra driver can confirm this.
- `list(df)` produces a list of the column names of a dataframe and drops all the data
- `dd.DataFrame`, if you read the [docs](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame) is not constructed like this.

What you probably want to do is a) make a function that returns one partition of the data, b) delay this function and call with the various values of the partitions c) use `dd.from_delayed` to make the dask dataframe. E.g., assuming the table has a field `partfield` which handily has possible values 1..6 and similar number of rows for each partition:

```
@dask.delayed
def part(x):
    session = # construct Cassandra session
    q = "SELECT * FROM document_table WHERE partfield={}".format(x)
    df = man.session.execute(query)
    return dd.DataFrame(list(df)) 

parts = [part(x) for x in range(1, 7)]
df = dd.from_delayed(parts)
```

Comment: thanks. That seemed to work, but when I run df.head(), I get:                  Metadata mismatch found in `from_delayed`.
Expected partition of type `DataFrame` but got `NoneType`                                 I specified the meta data with a list of tuples [(col1,dtype1),(col2,dtype2)...]

Comment: I also tried using an empty pandas dataframe as the meta where the column names and dtypes were specified, but that led to the same error