# Dask compute fails when using client, works when no client setup

Tags: dask

I am trying to use the dask client to parallelize my compute. When I run df.compute() I get the correct output (though it is very slow), but when I run  the same thing after setting up a client, I get the following error:

```
distributed.protocol.pickle - INFO - Failed to serialize <function part at 0x7fd5186ed730>. Exception: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

Here is my code, in the first df.compute(), I get the expected result, in the second I do not.

```
@dask.delayed
def part(x):
    lower, upper = x
    q = "SELECT id,tfidf_vec,emb_vec FROM document_table"
    lines=man.session.execute(q)
    counter = lower
    df = []
    for line in lines:
        df.append(line)
        counter += 1
        if counter == upper:
            break
    return pd.DataFrame(df)

parts = [part(x) for x in [[0,100000],[100000,200000]]]
df = dd.from_delayed(parts)
df.compute()

from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client('127.0.0.1:8786')
df.compute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function contains a reference to `man.session`, which is part of the function *closure*. When you use the default scheduler, threads, the object can be shared between the threads that execute your code. When you use the distributed scheduler, the function must be serialised and sent to workers in difference process(es).

You should make a function which creates the session object on each invocation, as was suggested as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53124641/3821154) to your very similar question.

Comment: Thanks, that was an oversight on my part. I put the creation of the session object into the part() function. This fixed the serialization error, but when I try to run df.head() it takes a very long time to run it. I defined the queries so that they would return 4 separate objects, each with an even number of rows, but am still having the performance issue. Does it have to do with how I set up my dataframe, or is the extra overhead it takes to run dask slowing it down that much? If I create a pandas dataframe and run df.head() the results are given instantaneously.

Comment: Check out the [diagnostics tools ](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-distributed.html) to figure out what your system is spending its time on. It may, for example, be necessary to run in processes as opposed to threads, for instance. Also, you `compute()` to pull everything into your main thread, which is not presumably what you intend to do.